# delphi 10.2 HoursBetween function issue

Tags: delphi

```
var DT:TDateTime;
.....
writeln (FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss DD.MM.YY',DT)); // -> 12:50:13 12.04.18
writeln (FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss DD.MM.YY',Now)); // -> 12:50:15 12.04.18
writeln (IntToStr(HoursBetween (Now,DT))); // -> 17531640
```

Должно быть 0. Вместо этого 17531640. ???
Результат неадекватный при любом DT.

Редакция Starter, посмотреть код HoursBetween сходу не получается.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте использовать правильный модификатор дли минут и выведите 4 цифры года `FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss dd.mm.yyyy',DT)`

Comment: У вас разница как раз 2000 лет получается

Comment: Поторопился, людей насмешил.. Действительно, в DT был просто 18 год... Спасибо!

Comment: TDateTime в Delphi это double 1 - целая которого сутки. 1/24 часы. Это так чисто для справки :)